# How to get the TTL of multiple Redis keys from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to show a view of all keys that look like 'myprefix:*' and their TTL.
I can then allow an admin to either expire a key, or 'touch it' (i.e. add an hour to the expiration).

I can use `redisClient.keys('myprefix:*', (err, keys) => {})` to get my keys, but the `redisClient.ttl` command only accepts a single key, not an array. I don't want to iterate over the array and send n `ttl` commands.

I know I can probably use `multi` to send a transaction of `ttl` commands, but I'm wondering if there's a better way (in JavaScript - **not shell**) to get all the keys and their TTL in one/two commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resorted to using `multi`. I do understand both using `keys` and `multi` is highly not recommended in production. But the number of keys I'm handling right now is quite small (less than 10).

Using `keys` + `multi` to get the `ttl` of N keys results in 2 network trips, rather than N+1.

As it grows, I'll reevaluate the solution. I posted my code below if anyone ever needs it:

```
let getKeys = prefix => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      redisClient.keys(`${prefix}:*`), (err, keys) => {
        if(err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        else {
          let multi = redisClient.multi();
          keys.forEach(k => multi.ttl(k));
          multi.exec((err2, ttls) => {
            if(err2) {
              reject(err2);
            }
            else {
              let result = keys.map((k, i) => ({key: k.replace(`${prefix}:`, ''), ttl: ttls[i]}));
              resolve(result);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

This yields an array:

```
[ { key: '05460a69f7c0d313b7edfcca4f267cee', ttl: 3034 },
  { key: 'b1065bfa82408a10e2d2d0a50df1eef9', ttl: 3031 },
  { key: 'c3aeced2ef08f1c728f0b367c50a962a', ttl: 3019 } ]
```

Answer (score 3):

As Redis embedds a [Lua interpreter](http://redis.io/commands/eval), a solution would be to create a Redis Lua script like this one:

```
local keys = redis.call('keys','myprefix:*')
local result = {}
for i,k in ipairs(keys) do 
    local ttl = redis.call('ttl', k)
    result[i] = {ttl}
end
return result
```

Using ioredis, you can simplify the declaration of Redis Lua scripts in NodeJS:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

// This will define a command getTtls:
redis.defineCommand('getTtls', {
  numberOfKeys: 1,
  lua: "local keys = redis.call('keys', KEYS[1]..':*')\n local result = {}\n for i,k in ipairs(keys) do \n local ttl = redis.call('ttl', k)\n result[i] = {ttl}\n end\n return result"
});

// now invoke this new command, giving the prefix as a parameter
redis.getTtls('myprefix', function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The script is defined in your NodeJS application, but executed by Redis.

Don't forget that using the KEYS command in production is often a bad idea, as it scans the whole database in one operation and so makes your Redis instance unresponsive to other requests during a time which could be rather long (it depends on the number of keys in your database). If it's an issue in your use case, you'll probably want to use a [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command instead.

Comment: Whhats the significance of using use LUA? The code is already written in JavaScript. 

Your script's logic seems to be the same: call `keys`, iterate, and call `ttl`. So for N keys, we'll have N+! network trips - that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Redis embedds a Lua interpreter. This script will be transfered to Redis, which will execute it as an atomic command, then return a result. Look at [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) for more info.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is only one request to Redis in my solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm trying to solve this strictly in JS, and without adding another dependency (`ioredis`) or LUA code.